# BroadcastReceiver ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I've been trying to implement the simplest of things, each time you connect the device to a power resource, toast it.

for some reason each time I connect it, the application collapses.
And because I need to unplug and plug again i cant see the logcat so I'm quite lost on why it's happening

My broadcastreceiver class

```
public class ChargingOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private Activity activity;
    public ChargingOnReceiver(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        if(isCharging){
            if(usbCharge){
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Your battery are now Charging Via USB" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }else{
                if(acCharge){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Your battery are now Charging Via AC Plug" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }       
    }
  }
```

My mainActivity

```
private ChargingOnReceiver battery;
protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(battery);
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.search_settings_screen,false);
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(battery, ifilter);
    }
```

My manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".ChargingOnReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I worked as it says here:

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: `i cant see the logcat` logcat write to a rather long circular buffer. There is no reason why you wouldn't be able to view the logs.

Comment: the logcat doesnt show any logs, on both events of POWER_CONNECTED and POWER_DISCONNECTED.
but not seeing the logcat is understandable, the problem is somewhere withing the code

Comment: you declare the receiver in the manifest, therefore the activity in this receiver is null. Use the `context` parameter to show the toast (also registering in the activity is redundant. chose one registering method and stick to it)

Comment: it might be a problem that in the end wouldn't show the toast, but since i changed the toast to context and it still collapses I guess that's not the issue :\

Comment: After deleting the activity constructor on the receiver it manages not to collapses, thx alot! but still the toast isnt showing, any ideas?

Comment: you do use `Toast.makeText(context` instead of `Toast.makeText(activity` right?

Comment: Indeed look at the comment below, thats what i suspect im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass activity object.

onReceive() has the needed context use that and toast will appear

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
            || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    System.out.println("isCharging:" + isCharging);

    System.out.println("chargePlugType:" + chargePlug);

    if (isCharging) {
        if (usbCharge) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your battery are now Charging Via USB",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (acCharge) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Your battery are now Charging Via AC Plug",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that, thanks allot, the app is not collapsing anymore yet the toast doesn't appear when i plug the device.

any ideas? i suspect it might be they way i register the receiver i changed the original main activity to this 

`IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(battery, ifilter);`

Comment: @sharongur
I think you missed to create object of battery.
`code     
    private PowerConnectionReceiver battery = new PowerConnectionReceiver();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  this.registerReceiver(battery, ifilter);
 }
code`